# database connection / different behaviors, sometimes it works, sometimes not

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm building a register and login system using PHP and MySQL. I have 2 projects, the old one works perfectly, but the new one doesn't.

In my old project, I have an olddbc.php file which I require in the oldlogin.php and oldregister.php. In both files it is all I need to do to use the $con variable and get access to the database and do some stuff.

```php
<?php

$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'customer_db';

$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    $err_msg = "Failed to connect to MySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

But in my new Project it didn't work like this and I don't know why. I couldn't use the $con variable from the newdbc.php file. I tried different things and ended up with using a class Database with a method in it, which should get the $con.

```php
class Database{

function dbcon (){
        $DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
        $DATABASE_USER = 'root';
        $DATABASE_PASS = '';
        $DATABASE_NAME = 'users_db';
        $con;
        if($con === NULL){
            $con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
            {
                $err_msg = "Failed to connect to MySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
                return $err_msg;
            }

        } 
        return $con;  
    }
}
```

in my newregister.php I use this to get the connection and it works. I can register a new user and redirect to the account page..

```php
$conn = new Database();
$con = $conn->dbcon();
```

but in my newlogin.php the connection does not work. If I try to use the $con just from requiring the dbc.php like I did in my old project, the variable $stmt is empty, it redirects and shows the error message. If I try to get the connection like in the newregister.php it does not redirect, it stays on the login.php and shows a blank page.

```php
else{
    $conn = new Database();
    $con = $conn->dbcon();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);

    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        $err_msg = "Database Problems";
        header("Location: ../index.php?logError=".$err_msg);
        exit();

        }
        else {
              //bind params and execute blah blah
        }
```

I can't understand why the `$con` works in my old project so easy and the new project is so laborious. It's the same version of PHP.

If I try it the old way I get this:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: con in login.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/index.php?logError=Database%20Problem
>
> PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_init() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in login.php on line 16, referer: ht-tp://localhost/index.php
>
> PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given inlogin.php on line 17, referer: ht-tp://localhost/index.php

If I try it the new way, nothing happens.

Comment: What error message do you get from the server? What does the server log say?

Comment: maybe log [msqli_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) so the exact database problem is more obvious.

Comment: Have you tried checking where `$con` is set to which value?

Comment: I edited the original post, there is the err log from apache.

Answer (score 0):

You really should implement this class following the singleton pattern.

```
class Database{
    // Hold the class instance.
    private static $instance = null;
    private $conn;

    $DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DATABASE_USER = 'root';
    $DATABASE_PASS = '';
    $DATABASE_NAME = 'users_db';

    // The db connection is established in the private constructor.
    private function __construct() {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new Database();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: vs code is yelling at me and says 8 problems cause of unexpected things like "names" and "privates"

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?